# angular 4 fetching nested json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

How can I access nested json? I have the following file:

```
{
    "user1": {
        "name": "john",
        "surname": "johnsson"
    },
    "user2": {
        "name": "Jacob",
        "surname": "Jacobsson"
    }
}
```

and so on. I need to make a table from this JSON data with fields name and surname with. How can I do this? I wrote the following code:
users.service.ts

```
export class UsersService {
    private _url: string = '../assets/users.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    getUsers() {
        return this._http.get(this._url).map((response: Response) =>
            response.json());
    }
}
```

and the users.component

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    users = [];

    constructor(private _usersService: UsersService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._usersService.getUsers().subscribe(resUsersData => this.users = resUsersData);
        console.log(this.users);
    }
}
```

then I just want to see my result using `{{users}}` in users.component.html but I see just `[object Object]`. So I obviously can't access anything else and getting the error.

Comment: You can't accessed it is not accessible.

Comment: try output it with the json pipe, `users | pipe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is flatten your JSON data file:

```
[{
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Johnsson"
}, {
    "name": "Jacob",
    "surname": "Jacobsson"
}]
```

You have named the file users.json, so you've already described that it will contain an array of user objects, which means there's no need to carry that level of hierarchy again in the file (user1, user2), in fact that makes them harder to get at. Your `users` file should be a single level array of objects, each with a `name` and `surname` property.

Notice also that the entire JSON block is wrapped as an array [{ }].

Second, your service:

```
export class UsersService {
    private _url: string = '../assets/users.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    getUsers(): Observable<Response> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
               .map(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

I make sure I type everything I can, as it makes it clearer when reading the code what types are expected, and the IDE can catch type mismatches for you, which makes debugging easier.

Then the component:

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
users: any;

constructor(private _usersService: UsersService) {
}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._usersService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.users = response;
                console.log('Returned Users:', this.users);
        });
    }
```

If you `console.log` this.users outside of the subscription, then the console statement will execute before the service has resolved the data, and you'll get 'undefined', even though the data has come back, it's just been assigned to your variable after you logged it out. Always, with subscriptions, log out your data in the `.subscribe` block.

Now what you should have is `this.users` which contains an array of 2 user objects, each with a name and surname property, and you can iterate over those in the template with an `*ngFor`

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}, {{user.surname}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was very helpful and everything works. But I have a file with the structure I have described, which is nested. How can I do the same thing, but with the original json file?

Comment: Does your file load with this code and log out to the console now? If it does, I'll write a function when I wake up to iterate over your existing file and convert it into this format so that it's usable.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks

Comment: Now I'm trying to make other operations like deleting, editing, adding new user and stuck. I'm so noob -_-

Comment: The absolute best resource for learning Angular is Todd Motto's Ultimate Angular courses, or if you don't have any money for them, read any of his blog posts. I'll add a formatter to my answer to unwrap users from your file format in a day or two as soon as I get back to my office.

Answer (score 2):

Your response is an Object, **NOT** an array. You will need to transform your response into an array, and then you can use `*ngFor` in your html table.

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate through the keys. Use `.map()` to return an array.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._usersService.getUsers().subscribe(
        resUsersData =>
            //resUsersData is an Object, not an array. Transform it.
            this.users = Object.keys(resUsersData).map(key => resUsersData[key])
    );
    console.log(this.users);
}
```

Now you can use `{{users}}` in your `*ngFor` in your tables.

Comment: This solution is awesome.  It helps me eliminate one level.  What should I do for a level deeper than that?

Comment: @Auguste do another `Object.keys` again in your map. Alternatively you can use `.reduce`

Answer (score 0):

```
your data format should be

   {
    "user": [{
        "name": "john",
        "surname": "johnsson"
    },{
        "name":"aish",
         "surname":"johnshon"
      }]
}
```

then you can use foreach to access all result

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "john",
        "surname": "johnsson"
    },{
          "name": "Jacob",
        "surname": "Jacobsson"
      }],
}
```

then you can access